# The program 'java.ori' received an X Window System error

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, system-error

I have an desktop application on Ubuntu 11.10 in swing and I have implemented a functionality that when any user click on one specific button, an input dialog box opens and ask user for input.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //Shows a input dialog asking the template ID to verify
       String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, 
            "Enter the Enrolled ID to verify.", "Verify", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

So the user fill the value and click on Ok button or even try to close the dialog box application get an error and crashes.

Error:

```
The program 'java.ori' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 2262 error_code 3 request_code 20 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Could anyone help me solving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: int id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "Enter the Enrolled ID to verify.", "Verify", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

Comment: Are you passing something that is not a Frame in `rootPane`?

Comment: @kiheru rootpane is JRootPane javax.swing.JFrame.rootPane. It is the instance that manages the contentPane and optional menuBar for this frame, as well as the glassPane.

Comment: @mKorbel int id showing error. It accepts only String.

Comment: Try passing the frame itself, instead of the rootPane.

Comment: @kiheru still same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the rootPane is not suitable as a parent for the JDialog which will be shown by JOptionPane. It should be a JFrame or an other JDialog.